# How to place a placeholder text inside the textbox

Tags: vue.js

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
     return {
        placeholder: 'Hello world'
     }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div class="container" id="app">
<h3>Search</h3>
<input type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
</div>
```

I can't seems to solve this problem.
Why the placeholder text is not show up inside the "input" textbox?

Comment: You want `:placeholder="placeholder"` (or `v-bind:placeholder="placeholder"`). See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes

Comment: love it, thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Please use v-bind directive to bind the attribute value as you can not use mustaches inside the html attribute.

Please replace your code with below syntax.

```
<input type="text" :placeholder="placeholder">
```